# Suppressing script errors in WebView2

Tags: javascript, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control, webview2

Thanks in advance.

In my WPF based webview2 control, I want to suppress any javascript errors that pops up.

Is there any equivalent in WebView2 similar to ScriptErrorsSuppressed flag in WebBrowser that can let me suppress the javascript errors ?

Comment: Can you use the `CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening` event?  It should trigger when a javascript dialog is opening.

Comment: @PoulBak: Yes, is CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening the only way to suppress messages ? How can we do that ?

Comment: Check the eventargs of the event. It lets you cancel the dialog depending of the properties.
Actually I have never seen javascript errors 'pop up' in `WebView2` - they just silently fail. May be it's caused by a setting somewhere (don't know where, sorry).

Comment: I cannot get the ScriptDialogOpening Event to fire, as a result the script errors just keep displaying, Any idea how they could be permanently shut.